# Serialize Lucene.net Document

Tags: c#, serialization, lucene.net

I need to serialize a Lucene.net Document instance.  When I try the following

```
    public bool Serialize(Document doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(doc.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(_indexPath, String.Format("{0}{1}",Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".xml")));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, doc);
        writer.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

I receive an exception because the Lucene Field type doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

```
"Lucene.Net.Documents.Field cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."
```

Any way around this?  Is there a more generally accepted way of serializing a Lucene.Net document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could, It wouldn't help you much since `Document`'s all members are java style getXXX/setXXX methods(not properties or fields). The simplest way would be to form  Field/Value  pairs by yourself and then serialize them.

For example, you can fill & serialize `MyDocument` class

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public List<MyField> Fields;
}

public class MyField
{
    public string Field;
    public string Text;
    public bool Indexed;
    public bool Stored;
}
```

Comment: So if you were going to serialize a Document so it can be indexed by another process, what approach would you take?

Comment: @Dzejms Don't serialize document, serialize your data in another format(KeyValuePair, your custom class etc). Indexer process can read this data, form the document and index it.